# How to pass values in the <Link to = {}> and get them from another component using [react / typescript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I would like to see how I can pass the id inside the `<Link to = {}>` using typescript. Then in the `SeriesSection` component get the id of the link.

SerieComponent.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Serie from '../../interfaces/Serie/Serie';

type T = {
  serie: Serie
};

const SerieComponent: React.FC<T> = ({ serie: { id, title, sinopsis, poster, rating, year, extra } }) => {
  let channel = extra.map(x => { return x.channel });

  return (
    <Link to={}/>
      <div className="post-2930 movie type-movie status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry movie_genre-action">
        <div className="movie__poster">
          <br />
          <a className="masvideos-LoopMovie-link masvideos-loop-movie__link movie__link">
            <img width="300" height="450" src={poster} className="movie__poster--image" alt={title} />
            <img width="300" height="450" src={poster} className="movie__poster--image" alt={title} sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="movie__body">
          <div className="movie__info">
            <div className="movie__info--head">
              <div className="movie__meta"><span className="movie__meta--release-year">{year}</span><span className="movie__meta--genre">{channel}</span></div>
              <a className="masvideos-LoopMovie-link masvideos-loop-movie__link movie__link">
                <h3 className="masvideos-loop-movie__title  movie__title">{title}</h3>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="movie__short-description">
              <div>
                <p>{sinopsis}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>

  )
};

export default SerieComponent;
```

This component is where I want to get the id of the link.

```
import React from 'react';

const SerieSection: React.FC = () => {
  return(
    <div>

    </div>
  )
};

export default SerieSection;
```

If you notice I already referred to the route

`<Route exact path="/serie-section/:id" component={SerieSection}></Route>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Home from '../Home/index';
import About from '../About/index';
import Footer from '../Footer/index';
import SerieSection from '../SerieSection/index';
import useStyles from './styles';

require('../../db/index.ts');

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Button component={Link} to="/" color="inherit">Home</Button>
          <Button component={Link} to="/about" color="inherit">About</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/serie-section/:id" component={SerieSection}></Route>
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having with this? Building the to= is just a matter of string templating, and the examples in the docs certainly show how to access path params.

Comment: I want to see how I should pass the values to the link for example '/ series-section': $ {id}.

  And how to get the id from the SeriesSection component

I'm new using react / typescript

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web

Comment: Yes, I know, but in typescript it is different.

Comment: In what way, exactly? Have you had a specific problem applying it? Give a [mcve]. In the code you've posted you don't seem to attempt either of the things you say you want.

Comment: In this way, <Link to = {{
       pathname: `/ serie-section / $ {id}`
     }} />

but it throws me error

Comment: [Edit] the question. But of course it does, that's not valid syntax in JS(X) *or* TS(X). You may need to go back to http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#string.

Comment: I already corrected my mistake

       <Link to = {{pathname: `/series-section/${id}`, state: {id: id}}}>

But now, how can I access the id value from the SeriesSection component?

Comment: Again, read the docs. I checked; it's definitely in there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I already solved the problem, I published it. If the solution can be improved let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to={{
  pathName: "/yourpathname",
  someProp:{foo:"bar"}
}}>Your Path</Link>
```

and than in you component that this Link leads to

```
console.log("test: ", props.location.someProp)
```

If the second component is class dont forget `this` keyword

Answer (score 0):

I had to refer to `RouteComponentProps`

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';


interface State {
  id: string;
}

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<State>{

}

const SerieSection: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  let id = props.match.params.id;
  return(
    <div>
    <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
  )
};

export default SerieSection;
```